# How to covert a mdf into excel sheet

Tags: c++, vb.net

i have installed SQL server Express Edition 2005
by using my application i am saving data in tables which is created in SQL Server
so that i have to copy in that data in to excel file
any please help me
how to do this

Comment: Is this a once off or a regular process? If one off Excel has lots of data import options.

Answer (score 0):

Read data from `MsSql` table and write each row into [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file.